# jQuery: Insert "&nbsp;" before last word of every <p>

Tags: javascript, jquery

For typographic reasons, I would like to replace the normal space before every last word of every `<p>` with a `&nbsp;`.

Is it possible to do this with jQuery?

```js
var lastword = str.split(" ").pop();

$("p").(" lastword").replaceWith("&nbsp;lastword");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam era.</p>
<p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
```

Would be verrrrry thankful for help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression and match `\s\b(?=\S+$)` (a space, followed by non-spaces and the end of a string) and replace with the `&nbsp`:

```js
for (const p of $('p')) {
  p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replace(/\s\b(?=\S+$)/, '&nbsp');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam era.</p>
<p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
```

Or, since jQuery is only being used for selection, may as well drop it and use `querySelectorAll`:

```js
for (const p of document.querySelectorAll('p')) {
  p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replace(/\s\b(?=\S+$)/, '&nbsp');
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam era.</p>
<p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
```

Comment: Thaaaaaaank you sooo much! <3 <3 <3 <3 <3

Answer (score 2):

For each `<p>` tag, get all of its words, pop the last one, join them all together with a `&nbsp;` before the last word:

```
$('p').each(function(){
    var words = $(this).html().split(" ")
    var lastWord = words.pop()
    $(this).html(
        words.join(" ") + '&nbsp;' + lastWord
    )
})
```